# Dataframe from Yaml: Trying to only convert strings to dtype string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to follow this flow!

I have a file with a YAML document, that contains this:

```
a_list_of_values:
- 0
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
a_string: "hello"
a_float: 1.23
```

Later I have to convert to .csv which results in this:

```
a_list_of_values,a_string,a_float
[1,2,3,4,5],hello,1.23
```

Even later, I have to ingest the csv into a Pandas Dataframe:

```
pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path_to_algorithm, "all_summary.csv"),index_col=False)
```

This results in these dtypes:

```
a_list_of_values     object
a_string             object
a_float              float64
```

I want to convert the actual string to a dtype of string (without using the column name, this is a watered down example).

If I use convert_dtypes(), both objects convert to string.

I want to leave a_list_of_values as object and have a_string as string.

Then further more, I want to filter out the objects out of the dataframe leaving a_string and a_float.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `str(a_string)`.

When I try it myself it looks like it keeps it as a string all along.

Comment: I appreciate the reply, however, I need a solution that doesn't use the column name as specified in the original post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).